# Spurious pathname for ASP.Net graph

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm generating a graph in an ASP.Net application. To this end I have included the chart control in the ASPX file like this:-

```
<asp:Chart ID="ourChart"
           runat="server"
           Height="500px"
           width="520px"
           BackColor="Black"
           ImageLocation="~/GraphTempFiles/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"
           ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
           ImageType="Bmp">
```

and have added what I believe to be the requisite features to the `web.config`:-

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ChartImg"
         verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd"
         type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler"   
       value="storage=file;timeout=20;Url=~/GraphTempFiles;" />
</appSettings>
```

The result of all this is that the page displays with a server error in the application:-

> Could not find a part of the path
>   '\MyDisk\MyDirectory\MyProgram\(S(32rdrd5zxhvc3rhq2szdxv2w))\GraphTempFiles\ChartPic_000001.bmp'.

Does anyone know what the matter is? (Presumably I am not supposed to create a directory `(S(32rdrd5zxhvc3rhq2szdxv2w))` at any point; the number in the brackets varies each time I run it.)

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, with Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248, as it says at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Looks like the session ID. Are your sessions cookieless?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I myself am not making any use of them; one might have been created on my behalf without me realising.

Comment: I fixed this problem in the end by copying in a web.config file from a previous project that worked. I couldn't see which parts were different but there obviously were some; something not obviously relevant needs to be set. This isn't really an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this error occurs since ASP.NET Cookieless Feature is enabled in `web.config` file like this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" timeout="60" />
```

According [Understand How the ASP.NET Cookieless Feature Works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx) to :

> UseUri: The cookieless feature will always be used.

In that case Url may look like this: `http://mysite/MyWebApp/(S(XXXX))/home.aspx`

---

There are at least two options available to resolve it:

**Option 1**, disable Cookieless Feature, use, for example,  *default* settings for `sessionState` element:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**Option 2**, specify the *relative* physical path for `ImageLocation` property of `Chart` control, for example:

```
<asp:Chart ID="ourChart"
               runat="server"
               Height="500px"
               width="520px"
               BackColor="Black"
               ImageLocation="GraphTempFiles/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"
               ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
               ImageType="Bmp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. The `cookieless` part was in the old web.config, but not the one I replaced it with.